# ¿Cómo crear un acceso directo a otra sección de mi app con flutter?

Tags: flutter

Muy buenas con todos, en mi aplicación móvil creado con flutter. Me gustaría saber como puedo crear un acceso directo, que sea vea en el teléfono como otra app (con su icono y ocupando su respectivo espacio en la lista de aplicaciones). No he logrado realizarlo.
He buscado en varios foros pero la respuesta no a sido para mí.

Gracias y espero cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Cuando dices "no he logrado realizarlo", a qué te refieres? Qué intentaste? Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el paquete de Flutter "url_launcher" para crear un acceso directo que simule ser otra aplicación. Este paquete le permite abrir una URL específica desde su aplicación y le da la opción de mostrarla como si fuera otra aplicación. Para crear un acceso directo, tendrá que definir un widget de "Acceso Directo" con la URL indicada, así como los detalles de la vista de la aplicación simulada. También puede configurar la aplicación para que se lanza automáticamente desde el teléfono cuando reciba una notificación.

Comment: Que tal, el paquete de Flutter "url_launcher", lanza otra app. Pero lo que busco es que se cree otro acceso directo en el teléfono, y simule ser otra app.

Comment: hasta donde sé no puedes simular otra App, para poner otro icono en la ventana principal del móvil o es otra app o creas una web estilo pwa para que se instale. Ten en cuenta que lo que aparece en la pantalla principal son aplicaciones

Comment: Esa otra app debería crearse cuando se instale la principal. He visto esa funcionalidad en ciertos antivirus para teléfonos (DU Speed Booster & Optimizador), que crea un acceso directo, para que cuando se abra mostrar otras funciones.

Comment: Los comentarios no se usan como chat. Para aclaraciones, pedirlas en la pregunta. Una pregunta pobre da una respuesta pobre.